# WCF User Management Technology Recommendation

Tags: wcf, user-management

I'm writing C# WinForm and asp.net apps that talk to a SQL server through a WCF service. I want to avoid creating my own user management system and would like to use an existing component/technology that can create/delete/manage users and roles. What would you recommend?

Note: I'm aware of Geneva framework but RTM for that is second half of 2009.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you would be using built in asp.net role management for your web application,depends on your applications complexity that how much can inbuilt role management handle for you.
Please check these links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

About Geneva, its a claims based access model which is being proposition from MS from long and finally we are seeing them. I have evaluated the Beta and seems to work fine , but dont know how well it can be used for production level code.
If you are looking for multiplatform federated applications , you can go with geneva or else the asp.net role management should be enough.

Again, it entirely depends on the complexity of application you are developing.Geneva can handle complex federated applications very well without writing much code.